# Auto-adjust image height depending on textbox

Tags: html, css, image, height

I'm looking for a way to auto adjust an image's height depending on a textboxs size. The textbox will change in height the browser window's size (

first, the image should match the height of the textbox
[image: first, the image should match the height of the textbox]

As the window is resized the picture's height is adjusted
[image: As the window is resized the picture's height is adjusted]

This is my html and css-code so far:

INDEX.HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img id="about" src="images/about.jpg">
    <div class="textbox">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....
    </div>
</div>
```

MAIN.CSS

```
.wrapper {
}

#about {
  float:right;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.textbox {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not concerned about image aspect ratio which is obvious from what you asked, you can try this:

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.container {
    font-size:0;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:table;
}
.container>div {
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
    font-size:12px;
    height:inherit;
}
.container>div.rhs {
    background-image:url(http://www.lorempixel.com/600/200/sports/1/);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="lhs">Dummy Text</div>
    <div class="rhs"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/588/

Trick is to use same image as a `background-image` in css instead of using `img` tag

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that:

http://codepen.io/jlowcs/pen/MYXXyv

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="textbox">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div
    ><img id="about" src=images/about.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.textbox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

#about {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 50%
}
```

Instead of using float, use absolute positionning. Just an idea, there might be a better way.

That way, you can keep aspect ratio, but width of the text and image will not adapt. Or maybe one could find a way they could :)